# Android multi threading error

Tags: java, android, multithreading

When I call finishRecord() debugger return error :

```
   05-09 19:26:58.491 17576-17576/? E/Zygote: v2
                    05-09 19:26:58.491 17576-17576/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
                    05-09 19:26:59.551 17576-17576/com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.example E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
                    05-09 19:26:59.551 17576-17576/com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.example E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@e6c815c
                    05-09 19:27:16.181 17576-17863/com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-187715
                    Process: com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.example, PID: 17576
                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: stop() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
                            at android.media.AudioRecord.stop(AudioRecord.java:999)
                    at com.github.republicofgavin.pauseresumeaudiorecorder.PauseResumeAudioRecorder$AudioRecorderThread.run(PauseResumeAudioRecorder.java:364)
```

My finishRecord method is :

```
  public void finishRecord() {
            mr.stopRecording();
            try {

                int recorderStateLocal = recorderState;
                if (recorderStateLocal != RECORDER_STATE_IDLE) {
                    synchronized (recorderStateMonitor) {
                        recorderStateLocal = recorderState;
                        if (recorderStateLocal == RECORDER_STATE_STARTING
                                || recorderStateLocal == RECORDER_STATE_BUSY) {
                            recorderStateLocal = recorderState = RECORDER_STATE_STOPPING;
                        }
                        do {
                            try {
                                if (recorderStateLocal != RECORDER_STATE_IDLE) {
                                    recorderStateMonitor.wait();
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                            /* Nothing to do */
                            }
                            recorderStateLocal = recorderState;
                        } while (recorderStateLocal == RECORDER_STATE_STOPPING);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IllegalStateException ee){}
        }
```

If I comment mr.stopRecording(); project can be run successfully

But I need to call mr.stopRecording();

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?